# Word 2010 Fields added in header section not recognized

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, ms-word

I added a field in the header section of a word document (I am using 2010 version). I went to Developer tab --> Controls --> Added a plain Text Content control.

In the code, I am looking for fields in the header section as below but nothing would come up as header fields.

Thanks for any help!

```
For Each oRange As WORD.Range In doc.StoryRanges
   If oRange.StoryType = WORD.WdStoryType.wdPrimaryHeaderStory
        If oRange.Fields.Count > 0 Then
                    For Each field As WORD.Field In oRange.Fields
                        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(field.Result.Text) Then
                            MessageBox.Show(field.Result.Text)
                        End If
                    Next
               End If
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content Controls and Fields are different things.

For Content controls, you need to test

```
oRange.ContentControls.Count
```

and so on

Comment: Thank you. It is recognizing the content controls now.